# jQuery fadeIn() following after()

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, jquery-after

I was looking to do a `.fadeIn()` animation chained to this `.after()`, but this doesn't appear to be the way of doing it.  Any suggestions?

```
$(clicked_item).parent().parent().parent().after(str).fadeIn("slow");
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use [`.insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/);

```
$(str)
  .hide()
  .insertAfter($(clicked_item).parent().parent().parent())
  .fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Added `.hide()` for newly created element. Try again.

Comment: You're most welcome. Do you plan to accept my answer or do you wait for another answer, maybe better? :)

Comment: @EmreErkan @ThinkingInBits You could have also given `str` a hidden state before being appended, for example `display:none;` and when inserted it would `.fadeIn` or `.show`

Comment: @FernandoSilva `.hide()` does the same.

Comment: @EmreErkan True, I was just thinking that if a user had js disabled that part of the website would stay hidden, it was just another option.

Comment: If js is disabled then `str` can't be added to page either. :)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @EmreErkan's answer, try minimizing your code. Use `parents()` and select the `id` or `class` of the div you wish to add the text after instead of using `parent()` three times:

```
$(str)
    .hide()
    .insertAfter($(clicked_item).parents(selector))
    .fadeIn("slow");
```

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comments, it is better to use `closest()` instead of `parents()` if you are targeting a single element, which using `parents()` with a selector usually implies.

Comment: `.closest()` would be better than `.parents()` since you're clearly after only one object, not multiple matching parents, but I do like using this concept much better than multiple `parent()` calls as it's much less fragile if someone adds/removes one more div to the HTML layout.

Answer (score 2):

$.fn.after() will return the element it was run on (in this case $(clicked_item).parent().parent().parent()). If that is the element you want to fadeIn then I see no problem. If you want to fadeIn() the 'str' element instead I'd suggest doing this:

```
$(str).insertAfter($(clicked_item).parent().parent().parent()).fadeIn('slow');
```

A more stable way of getting a specific parent of an element that doesn't require you to change the number of .parent() calls if you change the HTML is to use .parents() together with a tag name:

```
$(clicked_item).parents('p').eq(0)
```

Change the 'p' to the element you want to reach.

Edit: woops, too late.